# Laravel Model::create or Model->save()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering what approach should I use for storing data in the database;

**First approach**

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
```

In my Product model I have my $filable array for mass assigment

**Second approach**

```
    $product = new Product();
    $product->title = $request->title;
    $product->category = $request->category;
    $product->save();
```

Is any of these two "Better solution"? What should I generally use?

Thank you for you advice

Answer (score 18):

Personal preference.

`Model::create()` relies on mass assignment which allows you to quickly dump data into a model, it works nicely hand-in-hand with validation rather than having to set each of the model properties manually. I've more recently started using this method over the latter and can say its a lot nicer and quicker.

Don't forget you also have a range of other mass assignment functions `create()`, `update()` and `fill()` (Possibly more).